# Google map marker is replaced by bounding rectangle on zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm using SupportMapFragment inside Fragment and recent [Android Map Utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) for clustering. After Google Play Services update to 9.0.83 google single map markers are replaced by bounding rectangle on zoom. Only single markers are replaced, cluster markers are fine. Changing hardware acceleration parameter in app manifest doesn't change anything. How to fix it?

[image]

P.S.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

Comment: it appears someone file a bug report about the issue https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/276

Answer (score 7):

I use simplified version of @bishop87's workaround [from issue on github project](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/276). Also added caching for cluster bitmaps, which made it much more OOM-safer.

If you don't have Cluster renderer than use this one or move this code to your own:

**SimpleClusterRenderer.java**

```
public class SimpleClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<AuctionItem> {
    private static final int CLUSTER_PADDING = 12;
    private static final int ITEM_PADDING = 7;

    private final Bitmap mIconItemGreen;
    private final IconGenerator mIconClusterGenerator;
    private final float mDensity;

    public SimpleClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<AuctionItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);

        mDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        mIconClusterGenerator = new CachedIconGenerator(context);
        mIconClusterGenerator.setContentView(makeSquareTextView(context, CLUSTER_PADDING));
        mIconClusterGenerator.setTextAppearance(com.google.maps.android.R.style.ClusterIcon_TextAppearance);

        IconGenerator iconItemGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
        iconItemGenerator.setContentView(makeSquareTextView(context, ITEM_PADDING));
        iconItemGenerator.setBackground(makeClusterBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.simple_green)));
        mIconItemGreen = iconItemGenerator.makeIcon();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(AuctionItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mIconItemGreen));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<AuctionItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        int clusterSize = getBucket(cluster);

        mIconClusterGenerator.setBackground(makeClusterBackground(getColor(clusterSize)));
        BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mIconClusterGenerator.makeIcon(getClusterText(clusterSize)));
        markerOptions.icon(descriptor);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<AuctionItem> cluster) {
        // Always render clusters.
        return cluster.getSize() > 1;
    }

    private int getColor(int clusterSize) {
        float size = Math.min((float) clusterSize, 300.0F);
        float hue = (300.0F - size) * (300.0F - size) / 90000.0F * 220.0F;
        return Color.HSVToColor(new float[]{hue, 1.0F, 0.6F});
    }

    private LayerDrawable makeClusterBackground(int color) {
        ShapeDrawable mColoredCircleBackground = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mColoredCircleBackground.getPaint().setColor(color);
        ShapeDrawable outline = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        outline.getPaint().setColor(0x80ffffff);
        LayerDrawable background = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{outline, mColoredCircleBackground});
        int strokeWidth = (int) (mDensity * 3.0F);
        background.setLayerInset(1, strokeWidth, strokeWidth, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);
        return background;
    }

    private SquareTextView makeSquareTextView(Context context, int padding) {
        SquareTextView squareTextView = new SquareTextView(context);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        squareTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        squareTextView.setId(R.id.text);
        int paddingDpi = (int) (padding * mDensity);
        squareTextView.setPadding(paddingDpi, paddingDpi, paddingDpi, paddingDpi);
        return squareTextView;
    }
}
```

**CachedIconGenerator.java**

```
public class CachedIconGenerator extends IconGenerator {

    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mBitmapsCache;
    private String mText;

    public CachedIconGenerator(Context context) {
        super(context);

        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
        final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
        mBitmapsCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
            @Override
            protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
                // number of items.
                return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
            }
        };
    }

    public Bitmap makeIcon(String text) {
        mText = text;
        return super.makeIcon(text);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap makeIcon() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mText)) {
            return super.makeIcon();
        } else {
            Bitmap bitmap = mBitmapsCache.get(mText);
            if (bitmap == null) {
                bitmap = super.makeIcon();
                mBitmapsCache.put(mText, bitmap);
            }
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. You also need to replace `R.color.simple_green` with pin colour you want.

P.P.S. Forgot to mention, that this approach has negligible performance impact. So it would be better to update this solution with different approaches for Play Services 9.0.83 and others, if Google will fix this issue on next Play Services app release.

Comment: Creating own BitmapDescriptor for every item can cause OutOfMemoryException or similar on some devices. As I understand, it because cluster library shows all points before recalculate a clustered version.

Comment: @tse, Unfortunately, you are right. But I've updated my project with cache, and now It is way safer. I will update this answer as well today.

Comment: Yes, solution works - but creates a lot of OutOfMemoryException(s).

Comment: @Alexandr you promised to tell about better workaround without out of memory exceptions

Comment: @tse, thank you for your reminder. See added CachedIconGenerator. All optimisations are there.

Comment: Using this workaround, I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob.` on this, triggered by `BitmapDescriptor descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mIconClusterGenerator.makeIcon(getClusterText(clusterSize)));` in `onBeforeClusterRendered`

Comment: @Dellkan, it is weird. But I have no idea, why it happens. If you have the solution, just edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As per tyczj, this started happening when Google Play services (the proprietary binaries) updated to 9.0.x.

From the looks of the Github issue discussion, the workaround is to:

> Possible workarround from the gmaps-api-issues page:
>
> change
>   marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.drawableid));
>
> to
>   marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
>   R.drawable.drawableid))); //could affect general memory consumption
>   tho(?), I haven't tested with more than the app reported with in the
>   issue.

Also noting:

> I can confirm this issue. In addition to @Mavamaarten you must not
>   reuse marker images.

(Source: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/276)

Comment: What does that last part mean. "you must not reuse marker images"??

Comment: Basically, the workaround is you always load new bitmap instances... instead of sharing the same one.

Comment: I am sharing the same one and I don't get the bug. Is this normal?

Comment: @RayW but you can reuse the bitmap, just change the bitmapdescriptor to bitmap in your LRUCache

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem happens when: (1) I remove a marker with a custom icon or (2) set a new icon after create...

To solve the first case, you need to set the default icon before remove...

```
if (marker != null) {
    marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
    marker.remove();
}
```

To solve the second case, you need to add a copy of the marker with the new custom icon and later remove in the same first case ...

Until Google Maps Team fix this problem it is a solution...

Good luck...