# Why cluster marker icon not showing when zoom in or zoom out in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm trying to implement a cluster marker on my map,first, it shows me the cluster marker but when i zoom in, that expand and also show white square, i'll add some images to explain it better.

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX9g5.png)

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {
        private final LatLng mPosition;
        String Title = "";
        int Icon;

        public MyItem(double lat, double lng, String title, int icon) {
            mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            Title = title;
            Icon = icon;
        }

        @Override
        public LatLng getPosition() {
            return mPosition;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return Title;
        }

        public int getIcon() {
            return Icon;
        }
    }
class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {


        public OwnIconRendered() {
            super(MapActivity.this, googleMap, mClusterManager);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(item.getIcon()));
            markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            super.onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster, markerOptions);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code how you generated the markers?
Also, is internet fast?

Comment: yes I just edit the answer.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opened issue on gmaps-api-issues, look here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9765

Also look here: [Google map marker is replaced by bounding rectangle on zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211274/google-map-marker-is-replaced-by-bounding-rectangle-on-zoom/37431561)

Some workarounds are also described there.

Comment: thank you very much