# Android missing marker images

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, markerclusterer

Hello i am curently developing an app with google maps and costum markers with clustering but have som issues with cluster images as seen below on screenshot

http://prntscr.com/b9pgli

this happens on zooming out or in , some of them are visible but some of them is replaced with the white square (cluster is a square not marker), is there some solution on this ? couldnt find on google/stackoverflow

edit:

basicly i am using the sample code from 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#simple

Comment: Are you updating the marker icon after adding them to the map??

Comment: no, i am using the default icons

Comment: Similar problem has happened to me when i tried to access all markers and change their icons in a loop. It was a rendering issue. Later I just selected the marker to update and changed its icon. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a related issue about your problem, You can check it [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/276). One workaround is to avoid the SparseArray object, used in official DefaultClusterRender.java (private SparseArray mIcons = new SparseArray();).

Just make the cluster icon every time, setting background color and text dynamically in onBeforeClusterRendered method.

Here is the full [working code](https://github.com/bishop87/share/blob/master/android/MyMapRender.java) of the one who answered.

Check also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316636/why-cluster-marker-icon-not-showing-when-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-in-android?rq=1) for more information.