# Android Google Maps in Fragment Clustering Bug

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, markerclusterer

I'm trying to make Google Maps in a Fragment. I implemented clustering which works correctly (mechanism). But sometimes the cluster icon don't appear as you can see above:

[image: Bug]

Is there anyone that had a similar problem and know how to solve it?

If you want I can include my code.

Comment: I'm actually having the same bug, I don't know why, but a month ago I did not have this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google map marker is replaced by bounding rectangle on zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211274/google-map-marker-is-replaced-by-bounding-rectangle-on-zoom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be and update of Google play services.

Until Google fix it, there are some solutions, see the answer of [@Alexandr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37431561/2989387) to solve it.

The method onBeforeClusterRendered of com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer seems to be the problem